# Show selected countries without data

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to highlight specific countries, but not show the data when you hover over the country. In reality this needs to be a `true`/`false` type data.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Country','Active'],
  ['Germany',1],
  ['United States',1],
  ['Brazil',1],
  ['Canada',1],
  ['France',1],
  ['Russia',1]
]);
```

How do I get it to not display the "Active" data on hover? If I don't include a second column in that data array, nothing shows.

Example:

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country','Active'],
      ['Germany',1],
      ['United States',1],
      ['Brazil',1],
      ['Canada',1],
      ['France',1],
      ['Russia',1]
    ]);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#052c60']},
        datalessRegionColor: '#FFFFFF'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 1600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options), set tooltip.trigger to 'none'

```
    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#052c60']},
        datalessRegionColor: '#FFFFFF',
        tooltip: {trigger:'none'}
    };
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o3n1148/2/)

code snippet:

```js
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Active'],
          ['Germany', 1],
          ['United States', 1],
          ['Brazil', 1],
          ['Canada', 1],
          ['France', 1],
          ['Russia', 1]
        ]);

        var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
          colorAxis: {
            colors: ['#052c60']
          },
          datalessRegionColor: '#FFFFFF',
          tooltip: {
            trigger: 'none'
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 1600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: But I still want the hover tooltip to show the country name - those smaller countries many people (or those geographically challenged like most Americans) won't know without the tooltip.